# VM won't see network

Tags: windows-7, networking, vmware-workstation

I have a win7 64bit VM running on Vmware 7 workstation on a host (win7 64bit). The vm was able to see the network just fine, but now it cannot. I was running 6.5.3 and installed vmware 7 then rebuilt the vm. still nothing. The vm is set for bridge on vnet0.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching it to NAT and see if it then works, then back to Bridge.

Comment: This solution was helpful.  For VmWare v7.1.2 I switched from NAT to bridge, re-enabled network discovery(it should ask automatically if you are in network window) in windows 8.1 and all my local workgroup computers showed up.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for your setup, but you might find some interesting pointers here.

http://blog.nelhage.com/2010/10/dnsmasq-and-vmware/

The VMWare system has never been too nice with letting your host system talk directly to the clients ...
Good luck! Hope this helps!